# httpClient.execute does not show any response.

Tags: java, android, apache, http, debugging

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public Bitmap bitmap; 
public static String exsistingFileName;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d("Tag", "First Log Message");
    InputStream is=getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); //This gets the image


    ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    try {
        sendData(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }



public void sendData(String[] args) throws Exception {  
    try {  

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();  



        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/xampp/UploadToServer.php");  
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE); 

        Log.d("Tag", "Second Log Message");

        // format of image compressed - 640 x 480;  

        Bitmap bmpCompressed = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 640, 480, true);  
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        Log.d("Tag", "Third Log Message");


        bmpCompressed.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);  
        Log.d("Tag", "Fourth Log Message");

        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();  



        entity.addPart("myParam", new StringBody("my value"));  


        entity.addPart("myImage", new ByteArrayBody(data, "temp.jpg")); 

        Log.d("Tag", "Fifth Log Message");

        httpPost.setEntity(entity);  
        Log.d("Tag", "Sixth Log Message");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);  
        Log.d("Tag", "Seventh Log Message");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));  
        String sResponse = reader.readLine();  

    } catch (Exception e) {  


       System.out.println(e.getClass().getName());
       Log.v("myApp", "Some error came up");  

    }  

}
```

}

It does not give any value in "response".
Following is the **logcat** information related to this activity.

06-22 03:31:39.273: D/Tag(2889): First Log Message
06-22 03:31:39.289: D/Tag(2889): Second Log Message
06-22 03:31:39.414: D/Tag(2889): Third Log Message
06-22 03:31:39.539: D/Tag(2889): Fourth Log Message
06-22 03:31:39.546: D/Tag(2889): Fifth Log Message
06-22 03:31:39.546: D/Tag(2889): Sixth Log Message
06-22 03:31:41.304: I/System.out(2889): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException
06-22 03:31:41.304: D/Tag(2889): Some error came up

Comment: It would be helpful to show the actual error message as well (in addition to/ as opposed to the class name of the exception).

Comment: In the catch block log the actual exception: "exception: " + e.getMessage(). Do not log like "third message" but "going to call compress". Anyhow it is clear: you have a host connect exception.

Comment: You are using `localhost` That is only possible if the server is on the same device as your app. Or on the same emulator. Please explain your setup first.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out. I changed it to a IP address of my localhost and still its showing the same problem.